# What is the difference between Bayes-adaptive MDP and a Belief-MDP in Reinforcement Learning?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, comparison, markov-decision-process, pomdp

I have been reading a few papers in this area recently and I keep coming across these two terms. As far as I'm aware, Belief-MDPs are when you cast a POMDP as a regular MDP with a continuous state space where the state is a belief (distribution) with some unknown parameters.

Are they not the same thing?

Comment: Hi. Maybe, for completeness, you should also explain where you heard the term "Bayes-adaptive MDP".

Answer (score 2):

Both **Belief-MDPs** and **Bayes-Adaptive MDPs (BAMDPs)** are special cases of **POMDPs** and their state space is **augmented with a belief** over their unobserved/hidden variables.

In a belief-MDP, the hidden variables **can change** over the course of an episode. (Eg. Both the position and the uncertainty in the position of the robot can vary during an episode).

In a  BAMDP, the hidden variables are usually the attributes of the transition/reward function and are **held constant** during an episode. (Eg. In a robot locomotion task, ground friction or load - dynamics attributes, current goal location - reward function attributes. Though variables defining these attributes are unknown to the agent and the agent has to infer them, the actual variables remain unchanged during an episode)

**References:**

1. M Ghavamzadeh, S Mannor, J Pineau, Aviv Tamar - [Bayesian reinforcement learning: A survey](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.04436.pdf). Foundations and Trends in Machine Learning, 8(5-6):359-483, 2015.
2. L Zintgraf, K Shiarlis, M Igl, S Schulze, Y Gal, K Hofmann, and S Whiteson. [Varibad: A very good method for bayes-adaptive deep rl via meta-learning](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1910.08348.pdf). arXiv preprint arXiv:1910.08348, 2019.